# CSR Error: Cannot read property 'style' of null

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, jslink, client-side-rendering

Trying to color rows based off of the value of the "Status" column

However I cannot get it working as it keeps giving the following errors:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of nullTypeError: Cannot read
>   property '_events' of null

Debugging it, it seems to be failing on: `var row = document.getElementById(rowId);` and always coming up null.

Any ideas why it wouldn't be able to execute the getElementByID? This seems to be occuring whether I add it as a JSLink, or put it in a script or content editor... always the same error.

Code:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() {

SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
 OnPostRender: function(ctx) {

   var statusColors =  {
      'Pending Investigation' : '#FFF1AD',  
      'Under Investigation' : '#FFD800',
      'Completed' : '#01DF3A' 
   };

   var rows = ctx.ListData.Row;
   for (var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
   {
      var status = rows[i]["Status"];
      var rowId = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, rows[i]);
      var row = document.getElementById(rowId); 
      row.style.backgroundColor = statusColors[status];
   }
 }
}); 

});
```

Comment: Can you post any of the source HTML? There needs to be a table row element `<tr>` on the page with an `id` attribute, that matches the value of `rowId` your passing...

Answer (score 0):

so? What is rowId? And does it exist on the page.
Your code looks fine at first sight.

BTW You can achieve the same effect without CSR and JSlink connection in a Calculated Columnn set to datatype=Number with Formula:

```
=[Status]
&"<img src=""/_layouts/images/blank.gif"" onload=""{"
  &"var row=this;while(row.tagName!='TR'){row=row.parentNode}"
  &"row.style.backgroundColor='#"
  &IF([Status]="Pending Investigation","FFF1AD",IF([Status]="Completed","01DF3A","FFD800"))
&"'}"">"
```

Just works everywhere you display this Column. *pros* and *cons* versus CSR/JSlink at http://www.viewmaster365.com/#/How